# if date is -10 days from current, consider as new title

Tags: php

in my news script, i have the news organized as .txt files, in the beggining of each news file there is [20.03.13] (eg) date format.

i need a small IF that will check if the date has X amount of days back, (such as -10).
if so, it will be added to the latest news.
right now it is set to IF date is = today's date, add to latest news.

how can i convert it to something like if date is smaller in 10 days from today's date, echo... and then we can change the FROM TODAY line to LATEST.

this is the code, thank you.
by the way, please try to minimize the changes in my script. it took me a while to write it and understand it... im not that good, sometimes peopl rewrite alot for you, don't put too much effort i'll appreciate any help given as long as it works :) thanks again

```
<?
$files = array();
if($handle = opendir( 'includes/news' )) {
    while( $file = readdir( $handle )) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            // let's check for txt extension
            $extension = substr($file, -3);
            // filename without '.txt'
            $filename = substr($file, 0, -4);
            if ($extension == 'txt')
                $files[] = $filename; // or $filename
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
rsort($files);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    // get post date
    $postdate = substr($file, 0, 10);
    // get todays date
    $todaysdate = date("[d.m.y]");

    if($postdate == $todaysdate)
    {
        echo "<h3 style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;\">&bull; FROM TODAY:</h3>";
        echo "<a href=\"?module=news&read=$file\"><h2 style=\"background:url('images/h2today.jpg') no-repeat;\">$file</h2></a>";
        echo "<h3 style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;\">&bull; FROM EARLIER:</h3>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a href="?module=news&read=' . $file . '"><h2 style="margin: 4px;">' . $file . "</h2></a>";
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first let's convert the date to a standard format, and then convert it to the Unix timestamp:

```
 $postdate = substr($file, 0, 10);

 //Removing the '[' ']' characters...
 $postdate = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $postdate);

 //Splitting the date into an array
 $postdate = explode('.', $postdate);

 //Now we have an array with this format: array(0 => 'day', 1 => 'month', 2 => 'year');

 //Let's convert the year to 20xx (two thousand and blabla)...
 $postdate[2] = '20'.$postdate[2]; //You'll have to change this line in 87 years =D

 //Now we join our date array in a string with the following format: Y-m-d
 $postdate = implode('-', array_reverse($postdate)); //We have to reverse the array because 'year' comes first.

 //And now we convert the date to Unix timestamp
 $postdate = strtotime($postdate);

 //And finally we can check if the post time is bigger or equal than [now minus 10 days]:

 $time_now = time();

 if (($time_now - (3600*24*10)) <= $postdate)
 {
     //Passed, the rest of my script goes here
 }
 else //(Optional)
 {
     //The news has been posted more than 10 days ago
 }
```

That's it! Good luck.

I hope I haven't missed anything :)

Answer (score 1):

Using http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
$date = "[20.5.13]";
$date = strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', str_replace ( '[' , '' , str_replace ( ']' , '' , $date))))

if((time() - (60*60*24*10)) > $date) {
  //do something
}else{
  //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// get post date
$postdate = substr($file, 0, 10);  // 20.03.13
// get todays date
$todaysdate = date("[d.m.y]");  // 20.03.13
```

it may be difficult to check these dates for which one is greater or whatever. but if you convert them to unixtimestamp then it's done

this will be your IF statement

```
if( (timestamp_today - numberof seconds in 10 days ) < timestamp_posted) { your code goes here }
```

lemme help you in getting these time stamps aswell

today's time stamp - use time() function you get it

posted date time stamp - mktime(hour,minute,sec,month,day,year)

in your case posted date is [20.03.13] so yew have to separate out day,month, year from it.

```
 //Removing the '[' ']' characters..
 $postdate = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $postdate);
//Splitting the date into an array
$postdate = explode('.', $postdate);
```

now use `mktime(0,0,0,$postdate[0],$postdate[1],$postdate[2])`

but make sure to put parameters in place.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` can help you (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).  This will format the date 10 days ago in the  `[d.m.y]` format you are using:

```
$todaysdate = date("[d.m.y]",strtotime("10 days ago"));
```

Comment: i couldn't get it working. tried many ways. how can i IF it ?